# Offline foward geocoding

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, core-location

In my location based iPhone app I like to let it also work with no network availability. I have a normal google map. The app works with forward geocoding so when a city or country is typed in, I need the longitude and latitude. Can this work on a offline basis and how?

Comment: Well, this would need a database of every city in the world to be stored locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a database here:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite

Go for the CSV/Zip GeoLite City database.  It has an archive of data going back to 2009.  Make sure to download the latest one, at the bottom (GeoLiteCity_20130101.zip).  You could also go for the gzip, or binary data version, but I don't know the exact format of the binary data.  It's explained somewhere on the website.

The CSV archive has two CSV files.  GeoLiteCity-Location.csv has a rather large database of cities (which you would probably want to convert into a format that would be able to be searched faster than an array, and hopefully take up less space).  It contains the country, region (eg State), city, latitude and longitude for just under 400,000 cities across the globe.  The other file contains IP ranges for those cities, if you also need that.

Comment: Note: The data could also stand to be cleaned up a bit.  There are some duplicate entries w.r.t. country/region/city/location (there is other data within those duplicates which differs).  Plenty of city names contain non-ASCII characters and may be difficult to search.